# Packaging of cruisecontrol on debian

Tags: debian, package, cruisecontrol

To be quickly

today we can find a cruisecontrol debian package released on 2.3.1 ( from 2005 )

For a personal opensource project based on phpUnderControl i need to update this package to the latest release ( 2.8.3 from january 2010 )

I have following all steps from the official ubuntu documentation about packaging a software with pbuilder

the last used command :

`sudo pbuilder build *.dsc`

therefore i've got an error with the unit testing of the package ( junit ) in the fresh chrooted environment

if i call ant in the source folder this is ok but when i try with pbuilder to create the package i've got this error :

here the trace :

```
root@sqli-vm:~/PIC/CC/test# sudo pbuilder build *.dsc
W: /home/sqli/.pbuilderrc does not exist
I: using fakeroot in build.
Current time: Wed Feb  3 11:13:39 CET 2010
pbuilder-time-stamp: 1265192019
Building the build Environment
 -> extracting base tarball [/var/cache/pbuilder/base.tgz]
 -> creating local configuration
 -> copying local configuration
 -> mounting /proc filesystem
 -> mounting /dev/pts filesystem
 -> policy-rc.d already exists
Obtaining the cached apt archive contents
Installing the build-deps
 -> Attempting to satisfy build-dependencies
 -> Creating pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy package
Package: pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy
Version: 0.invalid.0
Architecture: i386
Maintainer: Debian Pbuilder Team <pbuilder-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Description: Dummy package to satisfy dependencies with aptitude - created by pbuilder
 This package was created automatically by pbuilder and should
Depends: ant, debhelper (>= 5)
dpkg-deb: building package `pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy' in `/tmp/satisfydepends-aptitude/pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy.deb'.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
aptitude is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Selecting previously deselected package pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy.
(Reading database ... 18446 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy (from .../pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy.deb) ...
Setting up pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy (0.invalid.0) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Initializing package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
Building tag database... Done
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
Writing extended state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
Building tag database... Done
 -> Finished parsing the build-deps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fakeroot
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/114kB of archives.
After this operation, 451kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package fakeroot.
(Reading database ... 18446 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.9ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.9ubuntu1) ...

Copying back the cached apt archive contents
Copying source file
    -> copying [cruisecontrol_2.8.3-1.dsc]
    -> copying [./cruisecontrol_2.8.3.orig.tar.gz]
    -> copying [./cruisecontrol_2.8.3-1.diff.gz]
Extracting source
dpkg-source: warning: extracting unsigned source package (./cruisecontrol_2.8.3-1.dsc)
dpkg-source: extracting cruisecontrol in cruisecontrol-2.8.3
dpkg-source: unpacking cruisecontrol_2.8.3.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: applying ./cruisecontrol_2.8.3-1.diff.gz
 -> Building the package
dpkg-buildpackage: set CPPFLAGS to default value:
dpkg-buildpackage: set CFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CXXFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set FFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set LDFLAGS to default value: -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: source package cruisecontrol
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.8.3-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by SQLI <alexis.gruet@kroknet.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
# Add here commands to clean up after the build process.
(cd main; ant clean)
Buildfile: build.xml

clean:

clean:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b cruisecontrol-2.8.3
dpkg-source: building cruisecontrol using existing cruisecontrol_2.8.3.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: building cruisecontrol in cruisecontrol_2.8.3-1.diff.gz
dpkg-source: warning: file main/loggers/build.xml has no final newline (either original or modified version)
dpkg-source: building cruisecontrol in cruisecontrol_2.8.3-1.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh_testdir
# Add here commands to configure the package.
touch configure-stamp
dh_testdir
#/usr/bin/make -s -f debian/Makefile prefix=`pwd`/debian/tmp lib
(cd main; ant)
Buildfile: build.xml

clean:

clean:

checklabel:
     [echo] Java: 1.5.0 (GNU libgcj)
     [echo]    in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.2-1.5.0.0/jre
     [echo] Ant: Apache Ant version 1.7.0 compiled on August 29 2007
     [echo]    in /usr/share/ant
     [echo] CruiseControl: 2.8.3

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/target/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/target/test-classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/target/tmp
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/target/test-results
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/target/emma-results

logger.jar:

clean:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/classes
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/test-classes
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/test-classes

[b]test:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/test-results
    [junit] Running net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.builders.AntOutputLoggerTest
    [junit] Testsuite: net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.builders.AntOutputLoggerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.459 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.459 sec
    [junit]
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/test-report
[junitreport] Processing /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/test-report/TESTS-TestSuites.xml to /tmp/null650765339
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Failed to process /tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/target/test-report/TESTS-TestSuites.xml[/b]

BUILD FAILED
/tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/build.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/tmp/buildd/cruisecontrol-2.8.3/main/loggers/build.xml:45: Errors while applying transformations: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: SAX parser error: reference to entity in undeclared doctype

Total time: 9 seconds
make: *** [build-stamp] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: failure: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
pbuilder: Failed autobuilding of package
 -> Aborting with an error
 -> unmounting dev/pts filesystem
 -> unmounting proc filesystem
 -> cleaning the build env
    -> removing directory /var/cache/pbuilder/build//9119 and its subdirectories
```

Any idea ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finaly i solved my problem...

The problem come from the released jvm on the pbuild chrooted environement plus some missing java libs.

i had to change some parameters on the pbuilderrc file and compile the base.tgz with ant-optional package + sun-java-6 jdk deb package.

Finaly i had to rebuild the makefile ( debian/rules ) and the cruisecontrol java source  cause will be done compiled.

So, i released the 2.8.3 version of cruisecontrol with deb package. 
working only on x86arch for the moment.